# Error when migrating for MiniTest to RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

I'm trying to migrate my rails application to RSpec. But I'm getting the error `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Relation` when running the specs. It says it's on line 10 of application.rb which is `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)`

**error message**

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

NameError:
  uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base
# ./config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `require'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:11:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# NameError:
#   uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base
#   ./config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
```

**Spec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::CertificateRequestsController, type: :controller do
  describe '#create_v1_4' do
    it 'worked' do
        expect(true).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
puts "Your env: #{ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV', 'test')}"

require 'spec_helper'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'pry'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
# binding.pry

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
if Rails.env.production?
  abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!')
end
require 'rspec/rails'
# include Warden::Test::Helpers
# Warden.test_mode!
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

**application.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require File.expand_path('boot', __dir__)
require 'oauth/rack/oauth_filter'
require 'rack/ssl-enforcer'
require 'rails/all'
require './lib/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors'

Bundler.setup
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

CLIENT_OPTIONS = ['aswesome.com', 'aswementer'].freeze
DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT = CLIENT_OPTIONS[0]

Struct.new('Expiring', :before, :after, :cert)
Struct.new('Notification', :before, :after, :domain, :expire, :reminder_type, :scanned_certificate_id)
Struct.new('Reminding', :year, :cert)

module AwesomeApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # set environment variables
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
      YAML.safe_load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
        ENV[key.to_s] = value
      end
    end

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib]

    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
    # Config::Integration::Rails::Railtie.preload

    # Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
    %w[observers mailers middleware serializers].each do |dir|
      config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app/#{dir}"
    end

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = 'utf-8'

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += %i[password password_confirmation]
    # config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Settings.actionmailer_host }

    # machinist generator
    # config.generators do |g|
    #   g.fixture_replacement :machinist
    # end

    # Rails Api
    config.api_only = false

    # turn off strong parameters
    config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :minitest, spec: true, fixture: false
      g.jbuilder false
    end

    # config.middleware.use OAuth::Rack::OAuthFilter
    config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, 'CatchJsonParseErrors'

    # Delayed Job
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/certificate/*',
                 headers: :any,
                 methods: %i[get post delete put options head],
                 max_age: 0
      end
    end

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
    config.sass.line_comments = false
    config.sass.cache = false
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'secure.ssl.com', protocol: 'https' }
    if DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT =~ /certassure/i && Rails.root.to_s =~ /Development/
      paths['config/database'] = 'config/client/certassure/database.yml'
    end
  end
end

require "#{Rails.root}/lib/base.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/asset_tag_helper.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/array.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/range.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/in_words.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/kernel.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/money.rb"
# require "#{Rails.root}/lib/subdomain-fu.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/domain_constraint.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/preferences.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/active_record.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/active_record_base.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/hash.rb"
require 'will_paginate'

# try to figure this out for heroku and rails 3
# class Fixnum; include InWords; end
# class Bignum; include InWords; end
DB_STRING_MAX_LENGTH = 255
DB_TEXT_MAX_LENGTH = 40_000
HTML_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE = 20
AMOUNT_FIELD_SIZE = 10
ADDRESS_FIELD_SIZE = 30
SERVER_SIDE_CART = false
# SQL_LIKE = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]['adapter'].
#   downcase=='postgresql' ? 'ilike' : 'like'
db_env = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
db_adapter = db_env['adapter'].downcase if db_env.present?
SQL_LIKE = db_adapter == 'postgresql' ? 'ilike' : 'like'

# uncomment to track down bugs on heroku production
# ApplicationRecord.logger.level = 0 # at any time
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.require_verification_value = false
PublicSuffix::List.default =
  PublicSuffix::List.parse(File.read(PublicSuffix::List::DEFAULT_LIST_PATH), private_domains: false)
```

**Gemfile**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'acts_as_publishable'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'declarative_authorization', git: 'https://github.com/xymist/declarative_authorization.git', branch: 'allow_rails_5'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'easy_roles'
gem 'haml', '>= 3.1.alpha.50'
gem 'json' # , '~> 1.8.6'
gem 'money', '2.1.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.3.0'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'rabl', '0.14.1'
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.11.1'
gem 'rb-inotify', require: false
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'workflow', '~> 1.2'
gem 'xml-simple'
gem 'yui-compressor'
gem 'zip-zip'
# Commented out while converting to pipeline
# gem 'jammit'
gem 'config'
gem 'oauth-plugin', '>= 0.4.0.pre1'
gem 'openssl-extensions', require: 'openssl-extensions/all'
gem 'radix62'
gem 'simpleidn'
gem 'uuidtools'
gem 'whenever', require: false
# gem "therubyracer", '~> 0.12.3', platform: :ruby
gem 'actionpack-action_caching', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 9.5' # https://airbrake.io/docs/ruby/upgrading-your-notifier/
gem 'api-pagination'
gem 'attr_encrypted', '>= 3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'dalli-elasticache'
gem 'delayed-web'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'delayed_job_groups_plugin'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'json-schema'
gem 'jsonapi-serializers'
gem 'libv8'
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.10.4'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.11.1'
gem 'public_suffix', '>= 4.0.0'
gem 'rack-cors', '>= 0.4.1', require: 'rack/cors'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'request_exception_handler'
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'unscoped_associations'
# gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary' see config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb for installation instructions
gem 'duo_web', '~> 1.0'
gem 'u2f'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
# gem 'simple_captcha2', require: 'simple_captcha'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'where-or'
gem 'whois', '~> 4.0'
gem 'whois-parser'
# gem "skylight"
gem 'authy'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'memoist'
# gem 'countries'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'timezone', '~> 1.0'
# required by sws-a1
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'date'
gem 'etc'
gem 'fileutils', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'forwardable'
gem 'scout_apm'
gem 'stringio'
gem 'strscan'
gem 'zlib'

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'letter_opener_web', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'memory_profiler'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-testunit'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Linting
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-performance'
  gem 'rubocop-rails'
  gem 'solargraph', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'builder'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'ruby-odbc'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end

gem 'foreman'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'swagger-blocks'
gem 'swagger-docs'
gem 'uglifier', '4.1.8'

gem 'rswag-ui'

gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '~> 1'
gem 'ed25519', '~> 1.2'
```

**test.rb**

```
SslCom::Application.configure do
  MIGRATING_FROM_LEGACY = false
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite.  You never need to work with it otherwise.  Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs.  Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}

  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
  end

  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the test database.
  # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
  # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
  # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

  # Sort the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :sorted

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

  config.eager_load=false

  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  #config.log_level = Logger::INFO

  GATEWAY_TEST_CODE=1.0
  # END ActiveMerchant configuration
end

#require "#{Rails.root}/lib/firewatir_url.rb"
```

Comment: Back in 2014 `rspec-rails` split the configuration into `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb`. The rationale being that it lets you run specs that don't require the Rails stack faster. `spec_helper.rb` should just contain the basic configuration of RSpec itself. Don't place anything Rails specific here as its required before the Rails stack. `rails_helper.rb` loads `spec_helper.rb` and then requires the Rails stack.

Comment: You may want tell us what Rails version you are using and include your `application.rb`. Rails has used `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` for quite some time and `if defined?(Bundler)` seems to indicate that it is reeeally old.

Comment: @max It's currently 4.2.11.1 but I think it originally started on 3.x

Comment: On 4.2.1 you should swap the offending line with `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`. Not sure that this will totally fix the issue which could also be because you are requiring factory_bot before rails is loaded.

Comment: @max Now its saying `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: Did you remove ’require 'factory_bot'‘?

Comment: I tried with and without @max

Comment: You need to require factory bot and database cleaner after require rspec/rails

Comment: @max still no luck. I've updated the rails_helper in the q above

Comment: Does the issue only apply to the test environment?

Comment: @max Yes, I'm able to start the dev server fine

Comment: Did you update rails boot/application.rb files when updating from rails 3? Please post `application.rb`

Comment: @Vasfed I've added application.rb above

Comment: Do you have you `config/environments/test.rb` file? Also are use using `bundle exec rspec` as your command to run specs?

Comment: @JoseCastellanos I've added test.rb above

Comment: @AntarrByrd, seems the `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/active_record_base.rb"` line is the culprit. I could see no such file in rails/lib - try to comment this line.

Comment: Do you have a test section in the `config/database.yml`? Mmmm weird why do you have those explicit requires in `application.rb`, was this project ever used without bundler?

Comment: @nathanvda The database is configured. I'm not sure what's going on with all the requires.

Comment: It looks like the order is wrong in the requires. I would be tempted to create a clean new rails 4.2.11 project, and then make sure the application.rb looks more like the "pristine" version. Remove all superfluour requires (and then re-add them if they are really needed). What is also possible is that your `Gemfile` is too restrictive: maybe some gems are only allowed in the `development/production` envs and not `test` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the order of the gems in the Gemfile. I had to comment out all of the gems and add them all back one by one while changing the order to fix any errors.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable is set to something other than `test` when you run your `rspec` command.  I've run into this before on some machines that have the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable explicitly set to `development` or something else entirely (which like others have mentioned will cause the issue you're seeing since the environment file is missing for that value).

In your `rails_helper.rb` file, try changing this line:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
```

to this:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
```

and see if your tests can run.  If that is the case, you'll want to either find where you have `RAILS_ENV` manually set (typically in a shell configuration file) and remove it,  or copy your `config/environments/test.rb` file to new one to match whatever it is `RAILS_ENV` is set to.

Comment: I've added the test.rb file above. rails_helper.rb is the only place in the app setting RAILS_ENV. Tried adding to test.rb and modifying rails_helper but didn't help.

Comment: Add this line to the top of your `rails_helper.rb`, and what does it output when you run the spec?

`puts "Your env: #{ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV', 'test')}"`

Comment: It says `Your env: test`

Comment: Please post your `Gemfile` as well.

Comment: I've added the Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Windows.

In order to run my Ruby on Rails app with Postgress and use PG gem, I had to set `RUBY_DLL_PATH=<your-path-to-postgresql>/bin`. Meaning that the RAILS_ENV environment variable is set to something other than test when you running rspec command.

The solution of @codenamev worked for me.